# Frequency bin of the positive and negative frequency

Tags: time-series

I am using this MATLAB tutorial for Frequency-Domain Linear Regression. There is one part of code they provide, where it is necessary to determine the "frequency bin of the positive and negative frequency", for fft and ifft:

`freqbin = 72/12;
freqbins = [freqbin 72-freqbin]+1;
tsfit = zeros(72,1);
tsfit(freqbins) = tsdft(freqbins);
tsfit = ifft(tsfit);
mu = mean(ts);
tsfit = mu+tsfit;`

Length of time series is 72, and 12 months is considered as one cycle. How there can be only one frequency bin for positive frequency? How do we know that it is exactly 72/12 + 1 (+1 is because first bin is for zero frequency)? Is this some formula or what?

I don't understand what is exacty frequency bin, and why there is only one bin for positive frequency? I thought that we have many bins in time series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are looking at is attempting to model only the `seasonality` of a time-series.  They first look at power of different frequencies, in the second figure in the tutorial.  They find a lot of power for the 1/12 frequency, as well as a few other harmonics, and also the 1/72 frequency.  But they decide that since the 1/12 frequency has the most power, and most of the others are harmonics of this, they will only model the 1/12 frequency.  You can see this from this quote:

> Based on the spectral analysis of the data, fit a simple linear
>   regression model using a cosine and sine term with a frequency of the
>   most signficant component: 1 cycle/year (1 cycle/12 months).

So you therefore only need one frequency bin, and its negative, since you are only modeling one frequency.  In other words, in this part, they are just using essentially the equivalent of a single sine wave (at the 1/12 frequency) as their model to fit the data.  All the frequency bin variable does is to act as an index and select the component of the fft() that contains the 1/12 frequency.

They then analyze their result (the autocorrelation plots) and find that they have indeed missed some of the cyclical patterns at other frequencies they did not model.  So then they add three more frequencies to the model.  Rather than using frequency bins this time to do the indexing, they simply ask for the 6 highest in power (6 because each of the 3 needs both positive and negative frequencies) components of the fft() with these lines:

```
[Y,I] = sort(abs(tsdft),'descend');
indices = I(1:6);
tsfit2dft(indices) = tsdft(indices);
```

You can see the resulting plot that follows now better models the time series since it includes more of the frequencies that showed increased power.

Comment: Thanks. I have more questions. In my example length of time serie is odd number, but it is also time serie is with monthly values and because of that I have frequency 1/12. Is in that case correct to round this number-frequency bin? Beacuse i need to use it later to choose terms in time series with same index like frequency bin, that is for for ifft.